# Using JSON dataArray in Dashcode, doesn't display binded information

Tags: json, datasource, dashcode

I'm trying to write a simple dashboard widget (possibly an additional webapp) that displays the information from a JSON feed. I've added the URL to a datasource, and it loads the info properly. It doesn't have any items.

This is the format:

```
{"username": "emb1995", "unconfirmed_reward": "0.02107742", "send_threshold": "1.00000000", "confirmed_reward": "0.11128238", "wallet": "key_here_but_removed", "estimated_reward": "0.00000000"}
```

As a test, I added a text element. I went to the datasource section and binded the string to the element that I wanted:

[image: datasource section]

Here is what my layout looks like:

[image: layout]

But when I run the widget, the information is never displayed:

[image: Information not being displayed]

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I went ahead and added the images for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really trivial but have you allowed access to the network. In the menu on the left you will see "Widget Attributes", click that then second box down "Network / Disk Access" one or both need to be checked to allow the widget access to either/both the the network or local file access.
If you have already done this and it's failing let me know.

Comment: Thanks! That totally slipped my mind. I implemented jQuery instead of dataSource anyway while I was waiting for a response.